# creating universal ios app with iOS4.3 and xcode 4.0

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, autoresize, universal

I need to create a Universal iPhone/iPad application using Xcode 4.0.

I start creating universal application, there is common app delegate and separate subclass of this app delegate one for iPhone and iPad. So I override the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and add a viewcontroller.

But my problem is I can't set the frame of subviews correctly.

```
[m_objMainTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(40, 330, 365, 700)];
m_objMainTableView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin);
```

The tableview goes out of superview only a small portion is visible.
But After I comment the autoresizingMask (second line) the tableview displayed in original frame.

I created the same code in older xcode version as an iPad app it works fine.
what I can do?

thanks in advance....